# Including a Python function in an R package without importing the entire package each time the function is used

Tags: python, r, package, reticulate

If I'm calling a function within an R package that I created, I prefix it with the package name in which it resides. For example, if I wish to use `gam` from the `mgcv` package in the `myfunc` function of my package, I could write something like,

```
myfunc <- function(y, x, df){
    mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x), data = df)
}
```

Now, say I want to use the Python function `indexes` from the package `peakutils`. I could write,

```
myfunc <- function(y){
    pu <- reticulate::import("peakutils")
    pu$indexes(y)
}
```

but this would import the entire package each time `myfunc` was called, which is not ideal. What is the correct way of doing this? Presumably, `Imports:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file is just for R packages. Or is there a way to include it there somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to `import` the Python library in the `.onLoad` function of the package being sure to specify `delay_load = TRUE`.

For example,

```
# Global reference to peakutils package - initialized in .onLoad
peakutils <- NULL

# Called upon loading the package
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  # Use superassignment to update global reference to peakutils
  peakutils <<- reticulate::import("peakutils", delay_load = TRUE)
}
```

While this loads the entire package, it does so only once rather than each time a function from the Python library is needed. A thorough explanation is given [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/package.html).